# Linking the same framework to multiple targets in CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have a Swift project with some local frameworks that are linked with the main app. One of the frameworks requires a CocoaPod that the main project also requires elsewhere. Obviously I'd only like one copy. That seems to work fine, but the unit tests are getting confused. This is a slightly simplified version of the Podfile:

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

# The main app target
target 'TheApp' do
  pod 'Instabug'

  target 'TheAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
  end
end

# A framework target that's linked by TheApp
target 'Logging' do
  pod 'Instabug'

  target 'LoggingTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

I believe I'm supposed to nest the test targets inside their subject. `TheApp` imports `Logging`. Both import `Instabug`. `TheAppTests` has a host application of `TheApp`. `LoggingTests` has not host application.

I get `Pods-TheApp`, `Pods-TheAppTests`, and `Pods-Logging` the way I expect. Sometimes I get `Pods-LoggingTests` and sometimes I get `Pods-Logging-LoggingTests`. (This turns out to be tied to the inherit setting. If it's not set, then I get `Pods-Logging-LoggingTests`; if it is set to `search_paths` then I get `Pods-LoggingTests`.)

I'm often getting errors that `Instabug` isn't copied into the LoggingTest bundle, or I get errors that `Instabug` has been processed twice. The app itself seems to work fine. It's just that unit tests fail. (There are several other local frameworks that don't have any dependencies, and I don't list them in the Podfile.)

Note that all the framework targets live in one xcodeproj.

I suspect I'm just writing the Podfile incorrectly. Is there a canonical way to handle local (non-pod) frameworks that have their own tests and their own dependencies that match the app's?

This is CocoaPods 1.7.0. I had the same issue with 1.6.2.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and I personally found it much easier to manage pods in a linear way and creating helper methods for referring each pod. This way when you share a pod among projects, you update the pod version only in one place:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

##
## Group pods
##

def alamofire_pods
    pod 'Alamofire', ~> '4.0'
end

def snapkit_pods
    pod 'SnapKit', '~> 4.0'
end

#
# Now, lets create all subprojects and main project pod dependencies
#

target 'MySubproject' do
    project 'rel_path_to/subproject.xcodeproj'

    alamofire_pods

    target 'MySubproject Tests' do
        inherit! :complete
    end
end

# Following same pattern for all other subprojects

target 'MainProject' do
   project 'Mainproject.xcodeproj' # path to main project

   snapkit_pods
   alamofire_pods

   target 'Mainproject Unit Tests' do
   end
end

target 'Mainproject UI Tests' do
    # specific pods for your UI Test
end
```

This approach worked the best and helped with running also subproject tests in the project.

Rule of thumb, also always make sure to remove old pod references from your project. That was causing issues in my case and throwing errors when building for unit tests I believe for subprojects. Cocoapods doesn't clean the old pod target references from your project's build phase.

**Note** `pod install` shouldn't change the pod target name if you don't change anything in your `podfile`.

Comment: Usually this is the "a-ha" moment when people realize Podfiles are just Ruby and you can write code to organize things to keep it clean!

Comment: So part of the point here is that there's nothing important about nesting tests inside their targets. They can just be peers?

Comment: For UI tests, yes. For unit tests, you nest it so it inherits the similar pods from your project. Also the thing that I dislike about nesting is you end up with long pod target names that make it harder to read.

Comment: Why the `inherit! :complete` in `MySubproject Tests`, but nothing in `Mainproject Unit Tests`? (Does that matter? Is `:complete` the default?)

Comment: I only have one project file, not two (not sure if that matters). When I try to do it this way, I get warnings about  "ignoring duplicated output file: ...Instabug.framework.dSYM..."

Comment: Don't remember the exact error message that I was getting, but `inherit! :search_paths` didn't solve my issue and was causing errors for subproject unit tests. And only test bundles. Using `inherit! :complete` fix my issue. Have moved to Carthage so can't duplicate it now. Can you confirm there's only one pod in your build phase `Link Binary` and there's only one `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`

Comment: I created https://github.com/maniramezan/PodTest as a sample project and tried `pod install` and didn't get any warnings. Let me know if there's anything in the sample project I should change to mimic the same structure that you're having

Answer (score 2):

You can create abstract targets that your real targets inherit from, thereby having 2 sets of dependencies, some of which are shared.

This is what I do:

```rb
project "NSScreencast/NSScreencast.xcodeproj"
use_frameworks!

abstract_target "NSScreencast-Base" do
  pod "Kingfisher"
  pod "R.swift"

  target "NSScreencast" do
    platform :ios, "11.0"
    pod "AppCenter"
    pod "FXReachability"
    pod "Colorkit"
    pod "SVProgressHUD"
    pod "1PasswordExtension"
    pod "OneSignal", ">= 2.6.2", "< 3.0"
    pod "Reveal-SDK", :configurations => ["Debug", "Debug-LocalServer"]
  end

  target "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" do
    platform :ios, "11.0"
    pod "OneSignal", ">= 2.6.2", "< 3.0"
  end

  target "NSScreencastTV" do
    platform :tvos, "10.0"
  end
end
```

This allows me to use the shared pods in multiple targets (here, iOS and tvOS) and have specific ones for each target as well.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Where do you put your test targets?

Comment: I only put them in here if I need to link with the pods directly (in this app I don't), but they'd essentially be siblings just like the TV Target is

Comment: So no need to test unit test targets? Just make them all peers?

Comment: My tests will @testable import MyAppTarget anyway, so it will be able to link with that just fine. However, I don't have a need to use SVProgressHUD directly from my test target for instance, so I don't need a pod reference there at all.